# How can I handle multi threading in flex desktop application?

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am developing an AIR application in Flex that fetches data from the server (through HTTP Services) and stores that in the local DB. But whenever the application interacts with the server, the UI of the application gets hanged.

I read about multithreading in Flex using Worker Class, but I am not able to use that in my project.

Could somebody show me a working example of multithreading in Flex AIR?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2f73111e7a180bd0-5856a8af1390d64d08c-7fff.html did this work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to fetch data from the server using HTTP services in background......  Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: "But whenever the application interacts with the server, the UI of the application gets hanged." - this exposes a problem that you need to fix before thinking about workers. Why is the application hanging? Flex runs in the flash VM which is async, so just because you did a server request nothing should "hang". can you post more details about your problem? Unless you have an incredible amount of client side processing (that you should challenge) I don't see how this could hang if you're not blocking the UI yourself.

Comment: Thank for your reply but my problem is that i want to do send more than one request to the server at a time

Suppose i have some content on the server which also have the path of any image within it once the content is Downloaded and the path of image is saved in Local DB then i want 

there should be 2 threads :

1: first one which will request for the next Content.
2. Second one which will request to download the Earlier Content Image into the Local Disk.


I want to run both process Parallel.

Comment: You can run multiple requests at the same time - there is no need of workers at all!

Comment: I tried multiple request at same time but process go in queue and executing one after another . For Example  i use setInterval method to request data every 10 second and also request for down load video from server 1 GB size  . If the video start download first then settinterval method goes in queue, only when the video finish download then it call and vice-versa.Any one know how to download(get) data parallel in flex or AS.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, can we see some of your code. The interface freezing sounds like you are performing an synchronous operation. Since you are using HTTPService this should not be the case since HTTP requests are asynchronous. You may also want to make sure that your concurrency property is set to "multiple" in your HTTPService if required on your code.